# Is possible monitoring a connection to IP Adress and Port without TelNet and with CronTab repeatedly?

Tags: linux, networking, connection, cron, telnet

I have some troubles with a SAP Server. Randomly we found disconnection error on our client.
There is some method or command in order to trace connection status with an host? I allways used Telnet but in this case is required monitoring the connection on night long and trace in some way "time" and "status".

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does netstat give you the information you need about the connection status?

Comment: Alternatively does SAP write a log file you can monitor with fail2ban?